# Nodejs - buffer issue on db insert

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've built a nodejs application - and on run for the first time it creates the db schema and inserts pre-data/test data into the system.

I've just added various buffers to a picture gallery - initially it was just one folder, but my requirements in full I've needed to make four. I am unsure if this has caused an issue in production as I get a db - "Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes" error. I tried reducing the size of the images but nothing seemed to take.

Is it the way I am trying to insert the records with different buffers, and the buffers are not yet ready?

I've had to comment out the section for now. Do I need to do a batch insert for different buffers?

I am unsure how to increase the max allowed packet - my access to via mysql workbench indicates I don't have sufficient privileges.

```
function createGardenTable(db) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    db.query(
      `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}.garden_tbl (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        name VARCHAR(255),
        short_description VARCHAR(255),
        long_description VARCHAR(255),
        type VARCHAR(255),
        image_day LONGBLOB DEFAULT NULL,
        image_night LONGBLOB DEFAULT NULL,
        createdAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        updatedAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      )`,
      async function(error, result) {
        console.log(error, result)
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error creating Garden table:', error);
          reject(error)
        } else {
          console.log('Garden_tbl table created!');
          
          /*
          const englishDayFolderPath = __dirname + '/temp/gardens/english_day';
          const englishNightFolderPath = __dirname + '/temp/gardens/english_night';
          const japaneseDayFolderPath = __dirname + '/temp/gardens/japanese_day';
          const japaneseNightFolderPath = __dirname + '/temp/gardens/japanese_night';
          
          const englishDayBuffers = await getImageBuffers(englishDayFolderPath);
          const englishNightBuffers = await getImageBuffers(englishNightFolderPath);
          const japaneseDayBuffers = await getImageBuffers(japaneseDayFolderPath);
          const japaneseNightBuffers = await getImageBuffers(japaneseNightFolderPath);

          let gardens = [
            { name: "English Rose", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "English", image_day: englishDayBuffers[0].buffer, image_night: englishNightBuffers[0].buffer},
            { name: "River Mary", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "English", image_day: englishDayBuffers[1].buffer, image_night: englishNightBuffers[1].buffer},
            { name: "The Cottage", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "English", image_day: englishDayBuffers[2].buffer, image_night: englishNightBuffers[2].buffer},
            { name: "Angel", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "English", image_day: englishDayBuffers[3].buffer, image_night: englishNightBuffers[3].buffer},
            { name: "Elizabeth Park", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "English", image_day: englishDayBuffers[4].buffer, image_night: englishNightBuffers[4].buffer},
            { name: "Okinawa Waters", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "Japanese", image_day: japaneseDayBuffers[0].buffer, image_night: japaneseNightBuffers[0].buffer},
            { name: "Sapporo Park", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "Japanese", image_day: japaneseDayBuffers[1].buffer, image_night: japaneseNightBuffers[1].buffer},
            { name: "Kyoto Pagoda", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "Japanese", image_day: japaneseDayBuffers[2].buffer, image_night: japaneseNightBuffers[2].buffer},
            { name: "Osaka City", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "Japanese", image_day: japaneseDayBuffers[3].buffer, image_night: japaneseNightBuffers[3].buffer},
            { name: "Hiroshima Blossom", short_description:"", long_description:"", type: "Japanese", image_day: japaneseDayBuffers[4].buffer, image_night: japaneseNightBuffers[4].buffer}
           ]
        
          const values = gardens.map(garden => Object.values(garden));
          db.query(`INSERT INTO ${process.env.DATABASE_NAME}.garden_tbl (name, short_description, long_description, type, image_day, image_night) VALUES ?`, [values], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error inserting gardens:', err);
            } else {
              console.log('Gardens inserted:', result.affectedRows);
              resolve({success: true, message:"Successfully created gardens"})
            }
          });
          */
          
        }
      }
    );
  })
  
}
```

the function getImageBuffers

```
// Read all image files in the folder and store their buffers
async function getImageBuffers(folderPath) {
  const imageBuffers = [];

  try {
    const files = await fs.promises.readdir(folderPath);

    for (const file of files) {
      const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);

      // Check if it's an image file based on file extension
      if (['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'].includes(path.extname(file).toLowerCase())) {
        const buffer = await readFile(filePath);
        imageBuffers.push({ fileName: file, buffer });
      }
    }

    return imageBuffers;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

--

update - I've managed to get it imported using 2 buffers - englishday and englishnight -- –

I want to try and get the other japanese bits in there - should I just insert the records separately?

Comment: issue is with database settings

Comment: just increase setting in database

Comment: I am unsure how or where to do that. Is there a way to check if the buffer is ready?

Comment: I've managed to get it imported using 2 - englishday and englishnight --

Comment: you should be working in unicode

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen please explain - nodejs with unicode?

Comment: readFile file should return unicode instead of ascii... also store your photos as base64